# Why do strange characters appear when I attempt to write to file?

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

In this program I attempt to write a file that displays an unknown number of records entered by the user. Each record has the following fields: First Name, Last Name, Address, City, State, Zip Code, and Phone Number. I assumed the best way to do this would be to define a struct Record with the fields above, then declare an array of Records that would contain as many records as the user entered. To accomplish this I would use a loop to get the inputs for each field per record, then if the user wanted to continue dynamically allocate an extra space in the Record array and continue until the user enters no. The program compiles and creates the file, but the characters written are totally weird. What causes this to happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Record
    {
        char fname[51];
        char lname[51];
        char address[51];
        char city[51];
        char state[51];
        int zipcode;
        int phoneNumber;
    };




int main()
{
    FILE *fileWriter;
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    char answer = 'y';
    int size = 1;
    int i = 0;
    struct Record *records = NULL;
    struct Record *records_temp;




    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        struct Record *records_temp = realloc(records,(size)*sizeof(*records));

        if(records_temp == NULL)  
        {
            free(records); 

        }
        records = records_temp;
        printf("First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].fname);
        printf("Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].lname);

        printf("Address: \n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", records[i].address);

        printf("City: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].city);

        printf("State: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].state);

        printf("Zipcode: \n");
        scanf("%d", &records[i].zipcode);

        printf("Phone Number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &records[i].phoneNumber);
        //stores all record info

        printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
        answer = getchar();
        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            size++;
            records[i++];
            printf("\n");
        }

        //open file

    fileWriter = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fileWriter != NULL)
    {
        if(fwrite(records,sizeof(*records),size,fileWriter) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to %s\n", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(fileWriter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file.");
    }
}
}
```

**EDITED VERSION**
I've modified the code and fixed many of the errors that were occurring, but now I am currently getting an access violation at  scanf( "%c", answer)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Record
    {
        char fname[51];
        char lname[51];
        char address[51];
        char city[51];
        char state[51];
        char zipcode[51];
        char phoneNumber[51];
    };




int main()
{
    FILE *fileWriter;
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    char answer = 'y';
    char a = 'n';
    int size = 1;
    int i = 0;
    struct Record *records;
    struct Record *records_temp = NULL;




    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        struct Record *records_temp = calloc((size),sizeof(*records));  

        records = records_temp;
        printf("First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].fname);

        printf("Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].lname);

        printf("Address: \n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", records[size-1].address);

        printf("City: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].city);

        printf("State: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].state);

        printf("Zipcode: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].zipcode);

        printf("Phone Number: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].phoneNumber);
        //stores all record info

        printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
        scanf(" %c", answer);
        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            size++;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
        //open file

    fileWriter = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fileWriter != NULL)
    {
        for(;i< size; i++)
        {
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records[i].fname);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records[i].lname);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records[i].address);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records[i].city);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records[i].state);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%d\n",records[i].zipcode);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%d\n",records[i].phoneNumber);
        }
        fclose(fileWriter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file.");   
    }

}
```

Comment: All your struct is dumped into the file, for example for `fname[51]` the 51 chars will be put into the file.

Comment: One point: `if(records_temp == NULL)`, then you should not do `records = records_temp;` and `scanf("%s", records[i].fname);` and so on...

Comment: Also, instead of using `fwrite()` use formatted i/o APIs to write each element into file.

Comment: I suggest using `char[]` for zip code (it includes letters where I live) and for phone number (my phone number overflows an `int`).

Comment: Also those two `int` fields will be "weird" when you look at the file content.

Comment: Think of what `scanf(" %c", answer);` does.  It calls a function and gives the function the _value_ of `answer`.  What even would `scanf()` use that?  Maybe if code passed the _address_ of `answer`?  BTW: Certainly your compiler should be waning about this line.  Save time, enable all warnings or get a new compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allocate memory, this memory is not cleared.

```
char *data = (char*)malloc(100);
```

This does allocate memory for 100 characters. But the memory can contain random data. If you write from this address you can end up writing random data into the file.

Clear the memory to make sure there is no random data.

```
memset(data, 0, 100);
```

Or for a `struct`:

```
struct Demo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

Demo *demo = (Demo*)malloc(sizeof(Demo));
memset(demo, 0, sizeof(Demo));
```

### Your Code Corrected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Record
{
    char fname[51];
    char lname[51];
    char address[51];
    char city[51];
    char state[51];
    int zipcode;
    int phoneNumber;
};


int main()
{
    char answer = 'y';
    int size = 0;
    Record *records = NULL;

    do {
        ++size;
        // resize records array.
        if (records == NULL) {
            records = (Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record)*size);
        } else {
            records = (Record*)realloc(records, sizeof(Record)*size);
        }
        // Get a pointer to the current record.
        Record *currentRecord = &records[size-1];
        // Clear the record
        memset(currentRecord, 0, sizeof(Record));

        // Ask for all data.
        printf("First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", currentRecord->fname);
        printf("Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", currentRecord->lname);
        printf("Address: \n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", currentRecord->address);
        printf("City: \n");
        scanf("%s", currentRecord->city);
        printf("State: \n");
        scanf("%s", currentRecord->state);
        printf("Zipcode: \n");
        scanf("%d", &(currentRecord->zipcode));
        printf("Phone Number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &(currentRecord->phoneNumber));

        // Ask for more.
        printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
        answer = getchar();
        printf("\n");
    } while (answer == 'y'||answer == 'Y');

    // Write all records
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    FILE *fileWriter = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fileWriter != NULL) {
        if (fwrite(records, sizeof(Record), size, fileWriter) != size) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to %s\n", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(fileWriter);
    } else {
        printf("Error opening file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane Using calloc() fixed most of my issues, but at the end of the loop when it ask the user if their are any records the program automatically exits, why is that?

Comment: I think some of your modifications might have caused the access violation in my edited code above.

Comment: Rather than `Demo *demo = (Demo*)malloc(sizeof(Demo));`, consider the easier to code and maintain `Demo *demo = malloc(sizeof *demo);`.

Comment: No need for `if()` in `if (records == NULL) { ..`  Just use `records = realloc(records, size * sizeof *records);`

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", currentRecord->address);` reads nothing into `currentRecord->address` if use just enters `"\n"`.  Suggest `currentRecord->address[0] = 0;` first.  Better to use `scanf(" %50[^\n]", currentRecord->address);` to prevent overrun.

Comment: @chux See the edited code, the changes I've made have seemed to fix many of the formatting problems I was having, but I'm still getting access violations at "char answer" when the program asks the user if there are more records.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with `fwrite(records,sizeof(*records),size,fileWriter)`:

- `struct Record` contains 5 null-terminated strings, so your file will contain 5 null-characters separating those strings, where you probably want newline-characters instead.
- `struct Record` contains 2 integers which are written into the file as binary data, and can most certainly qualify under "strange characters appearing in the file".

---

You can fix it by writing each one of those fields according to its specific type:

```
fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records->fname);
fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records->lname);
fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records->address);
fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records->city);
fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records->state);
fprintf(fileWriter,"%d\n",records->zipcode);
fprintf(fileWriter,"%d\n",records->phoneNumber);
```

Comment: What could I do to fix the problem? Would turning those integers into strings help?

Answer (score 1):

Answering OP's commented question asking why the program automatically exits, I suggest this (by example). Note the `' '` space before `%c`, which cleans up any preceding white space.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int phone;
    char answer;
    scanf("%d", &phone);        // leaves newline in buffer
    //answer  = getchar();      // reads the newline still in buffer
    scanf(" %c", &answer);      // skips preceding white-space
    return 0;
}
```